# Can I use a 1.5 amp 5v or 12v supply to power the esc and cd rom brushless motor?

Tags: brushless-motors, brushed-motors

I'm new here on the site, and I want to start the cd rom motor you see in the image below:[image: cd rom brushless motor]

but can i use a 1.5amp 5v or 12v supply to power the esc and start the cd rom brushless motor?  the source of this type: [image]

thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: This specific site is for questions solely related to Drones and model aircraft. You might be able to get a better answer somewhere like Electrical Engineering SE.

Answer (score 2):

Brushless motors need an electronic speed controller to energise each set of coils in turn. There are usually three sets of coils, supplied via three wires. The speed controller takes the DC input power and switches it between pairs of wires, while monitoring the voltage on the other wire to decide when to switch. This normally requires six transistors to do the switching and a microcontroller for the decision making.

It's possible that the chip in the first picture is a speed controller, but the fact that the board is supplied by three wires (of the same colour) implies that it is elsewhere.

CDROMs spin at multiple speeds, so the normal speed controller probably needs a signal as well as power to run, so it wouldn't be as simple as just connecting some power.

I think you will need to buy a brushless speed controller. A small one suitable for this motor would be $5-10. You will also need something to generate a PWM signal to tell it what speed to run at. Typically this is a radio control receiver, but you could use a 'servo tester', or an Arduino.

BTW, in the early days of brushless motors in RC, we often used CDROM motors, but to get useful performance we would replace the magnets, rewind the coils, and add bearings. Also the standard mounts aren't ideal, so really all we reused was the stator core and the bell.